# item does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer

Tags: typescript, graphql

I have a model `Location`, the relationship is with itself.

```
class Location extends Model<Location> {
    ...

    @BelongsTo(() => Location, "countryId")
    public country?: Location;

    @BelongsTo(() => Location, "stateId")
    public state?: Location;

    @HasMany(() => Location, "countryId")
    public states?: Location[];

    @HasMany(() => Location, "stateId")
    public regions?: Location[];

    @HasMany(() => Location, "regionId")
    public places?: Location[];

    ...
}
```

So basically `counties` has many `states` has many `regions` and etc. **I'd like to implement this as a `GraphQLType`**.

**What have I tried:**

```
const LocationType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "LocationType",
    fields: () => ({
        ...
        states: {type: new GraphQLList(LocationType)},
        ...
    }),
});
```

**Error I get**

> 'LocationType' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to specify the `LocationType` type to `GraphQLObjectType`.

Something like this:

```
const LocationType: GraphQLObjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "LocationType",
    fields: () => ({
        ...
        states: {type: new GraphQLList(LocationType)},
        ...
    }),
});
```